# Android 10: BLE pairing issues with RN4871 with app as peripheral

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android app acting as a peripheral server sending accelerometer data via notifications to the central client (an RN4871 module).

Things work fine if I manually initiate the connection from the RN4871 using the phone's randomized MAC address, but I would like to pair the two to make connection easier so I can do it through software instead of manually.

I send the bonding request from the RN4871 on the phone and the phone allows me to accept it.
`%INDI,0003,0100FFFF%%INDI,0003,0100FFFF%%SECURED%%BONDED%`

There seem to be some handshake messages which are sent: `%CONN_PARAM,0006,0000,01F4%%CONN_PARAM,0016,0000,0200%`

I think maybe these are updating the connection parameters to the following:

```
2021-03-08 10:01:26.932 16804-17751/ece558.bthornhill.edu.jumprope D/BluetoothGattServer: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=D8:80:39:F8:B2:77 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
2021-03-08 10:01:27.599 16804-17751/ece558.bthornhill.edu.jumprope D/BluetoothGattServer: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=D8:80:39:F8:B2:77 interval=22 latency=0 timeout=512 status=0
```

But then the app seems to freeze. I can disconnect the connection on both sides by exiting the app, and running the connection kill command on the RN4871, but when I set the app in advertising mode again, and try to connect to the newly listed bonded device, the connection never happens and it just cycles.

I can get things working again only when I unpair the device from the phone, remove the phone as a bonded item from the RN4871, and restart the RN4871 and the app.

I can't seem to pinpoint what the exact issue is. Any help would be appreciated.